# How to keep a fragment on the back stack on a different fragment within a tab fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

[image]

I need to keep a fragment on the back stack on a different fragment within a tab fragment, so that if I dismiss the button within current fragment, I get back the previous one. How can I achieve that? Here is my code:

```
HomeActivity.java

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    String mCurrentTab;
    HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        View homeView=LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.homeimage, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(homeView),TimelineFragment.class, null);
        View addView=LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.addimage, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(addView),AddFragment.class, null);
    }
}

This is the first fragment:
TimelineFragment.java

public class TimelineFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView timelineTv, profileTv;
    public ArrayList<TimeLineDetailsData>myListData;
    public ListView lv_timeLine;
    public TimelineAdapter myTimelineAdapter;
    View rootView;
    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_profile, container, false);
        timelineTv = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.timelineTv);
        profileTv = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.profileTv);
        lv_timeLine = (ListView)V.findViewById(R.id.lv_timeLine);
        rootView=getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        initView();
        initiatedata();
        timelineTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#614d28"));
        profileTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8f7f61"));
        timelineTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                timelineTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#614d28"));
                profileTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8f7f61"));
            }
        });
        profileTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                timelineTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8f7f61"));
                profileTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#614d28"));
            }
        });
        return V;
    }
    public Bitmap takeScreenshot(){
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        File imagePath=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/com.bpd.android.pay/cache/1.png");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try{
            fos=new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("GREC",e.getMessage(),e);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("GREC",e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }
    private void initiatedata(){
        myListData.clear();
        for(int i=1;i<=8;i++){
            TimeLineDetailsData tempObj=new TimeLineDetailsData();
            tempObj.shortDetails="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mauris mauris, faucibus a hendrerit eget, malesuada nec diam.";
            tempObj.Profileimage="";
            tempObj.DayAgo = i+" day ago";
            tempObj.ProfileName="Rajat subhra";
            myListData.add(tempObj);
        }
    }
    private void initView(){
        myListData=new ArrayList<TimeLineDetailsData>();
        myTimelineAdapter=new TimelineAdapter(getActivity(),myListData);
        lv_timeLine.setAdapter(myTimelineAdapter);
        myTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        Bitmap bitmap=takeScreenshot();
        saveBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

Here is the next fragment:
AddFragment.java

public class AddFragment extends Fragment{
    SemiCircularRadialMenu mMenu;
    private SemiCircularRadialMenuItem mStudy, mServiceTithing, mMeditation, mPurification, mSharanagati;
    ListView lv_sharanagati;
    ArrayList<SharanagatiDetails> mySharanagatiList;
    SharanagatiAdapter mySharanagatiAdapter;
    LinearLayout linAdd;
    String cacheDir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/com.bpd.android.pay/cache/1.png";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_fragment,container, false);
        linAdd = (LinearLayout) V.findViewById(R.id.linAdd);
        mStudy = new SemiCircularRadialMenuItem("study", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.study_icon), "Study");
        mServiceTithing = new SemiCircularRadialMenuItem("servicetithing", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.service_tithing_icon), "Service & Tithing");
        mMeditation = new SemiCircularRadialMenuItem("meditation", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.meditation_icon), "Meditation");
        mPurification = new SemiCircularRadialMenuItem("purification", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.purification_icon), "Purification");
        mSharanagati = new SemiCircularRadialMenuItem("sharanagati", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sharanagati_icon), "Sharanagati");

        mStudy.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mServiceTithing.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mMeditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mPurification.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mSharanagati.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mMenu = (SemiCircularRadialMenu)V.findViewById(R.id.radial_menu);
        mMenu.addMenuItem(mStudy.getMenuID(), mStudy);
        mMenu.addMenuItem(mServiceTithing.getMenuID(), mServiceTithing);
        mMenu.addMenuItem(mMeditation.getMenuID(), mMeditation);
        mMenu.addMenuItem(mPurification.getMenuID(), mPurification);
        mMenu.addMenuItem(mSharanagati.getMenuID(), mSharanagati);
        mMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStudy.setOnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(new OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(){
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemPressed(){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),mStudy.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mStudy.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });
        mServiceTithing.setOnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(new OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(){
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemPressed() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mServiceTithing.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mServiceTithing.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });
        mMeditation.setOnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(new OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemPressed() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mMeditation.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mMeditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });
        mPurification.setOnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(new OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(){
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemPressed(){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),mPurification.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mPurification.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });
        mSharanagati.setOnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(new OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(){
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemPressed(){
                mSharanagati.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),SharanagatiActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                //mMenu.dismissMenu();
            }
        });
        return V;
    }
    private void initView() {
        mySharanagatiList = new ArrayList<SharanagatiDetails>();
        mySharanagatiAdapter = new SharanagatiAdapter(getActivity(),
            mySharanagatiList);
        lv_sharanagati.setAdapter(mySharanagatiAdapter);
        mySharanagatiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void getSharanagatiList() {
        mySharanagatiList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            SharanagatiDetails tempObj = new SharanagatiDetails();
            tempObj.SharanagatiName = "Sharanagati " + i;
            mySharanagatiList.add(tempObj);
        }
    }
}

This class is used for radial menu:
SemiCircularRadialMenu.java
```

public class SemiCircularRadialMenu extends View {

```
//Static Access Variables
public static final int VERTICAL_RIGHT = 0;
public static final int VERTICAL_LEFT = 1;
public static final int HORIZONTAL_TOP = 2;
public static final int HORIZONTAL_BOTTOM = 3;
//Private non-shared variables
private boolean isMenuVisible = false;
private boolean isMenuTogglePressed = false;
private boolean isMenuItemPressed = false;
private String mPressedMenuItemID = null;
private int mDiameter = 0;
private float mRadius = 0.0f;
private int mStartAngle = 0;
private RectF mMenuRect;
private RectF mMenuCenterButtonRect;
private Paint mRadialMenuPaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);    
private Point mViewAnchorPoints;
private HashMap<String, SemiCircularRadialMenuItem> mMenuItems = new HashMap<String, SemiCircularRadialMenuItem>();
//Variables that can be user defined
private float mShadowRadius = 5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
private boolean isShowMenuText = false;
private int mOrientation = HORIZONTAL_BOTTOM;
private int centerRadialColor = Color.WHITE;
private int mShadowColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;
private String openMenuText = "Open";
private String closeMenuText = "Close";
private String centerMenuText = openMenuText;   //Not to be set using setter method
private int mToggleMenuTextColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;
private float textSize = 12 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
private int mOpenButtonScaleFactor = 3;

public SemiCircularRadialMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public SemiCircularRadialMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public SemiCircularRadialMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mRadialMenuPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    mRadialMenuPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mRadialMenuPaint.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius,0.0f,0.0f,mShadowColor);
    //Draw the menu if the menu is to be displayed
    //if(isMenuVisible){
        canvas.drawArc(mMenuRect,mStartAngle,180,true,mRadialMenuPaint);
        //See if there is any item in the collection
        if(mMenuItems.size() > 0) {
            float mStart = mStartAngle;
            //Get the sweep angles based on the number of menu items
            float mSweep = 180/mMenuItems.size();
            for(SemiCircularRadialMenuItem item:mMenuItems.values()){
                mRadialMenuPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT/*item.getBackgroundColor()*/);
                item.setMenuPath(mMenuCenterButtonRect, mMenuRect, mStart, mSweep, mRadius, mViewAnchorPoints);
                canvas.drawPath(item.getMenuPath(), mRadialMenuPaint);
                //if(isShowMenuText){
                    mRadialMenuPaint.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, 0.0f, 0.0f, Color.TRANSPARENT);  
                    mRadialMenuPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT/*item.getTextColor()*/);
                    canvas.drawTextOnPath(item.getText(), item.getMenuPath(), 5, textSize, mRadialMenuPaint);
                    mRadialMenuPaint.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, 0.0f, 0.0f, Color.TRANSPARENT/*mShadowColor*/);
                //}
                item.getIcon().draw(canvas);
                mStart += mSweep;
            }
            mRadialMenuPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }
    //}
    //Draw the center menu toggle piece
    mRadialMenuPaint.setColor(centerRadialColor);
    canvas.drawArc(mMenuCenterButtonRect, mStartAngle,/*18*/0, true, mRadialMenuPaint);
    mRadialMenuPaint.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, 0.0f, 0.0f, Color.TRANSPARENT);  
    //Draw the center text
    drawCenterText(canvas, mRadialMenuPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(mMenuCenterButtonRect.contains(x, y)) {
            centerRadialColor = RadialMenuColors.HOLO_LIGHT_BLUE;
            isMenuTogglePressed = true;
            invalidate();
        } else if(isMenuVisible) {
            if(mMenuItems.size()>0) {
                for(SemiCircularRadialMenuItem item : mMenuItems.values()) {
                    if(mMenuRect.contains((int) x, (int) y))
                        if(item.getBounds().contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                            isMenuItemPressed = true;
                            mPressedMenuItemID = item.getMenuID();
                            break;
                        }
                }
                mMenuItems.get(mPressedMenuItemID)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT/*mMenuItems.get(mPressedMenuItemID).getMenuSelectedColor()*/);
                invalidate();
            }
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if(isMenuTogglePressed){
            centerRadialColor=Color.WHITE;
            if(isMenuVisible){
                isMenuVisible=false;
                centerMenuText=openMenuText;
            } else {
                isMenuVisible = true;
                centerMenuText = closeMenuText;
            }
            isMenuTogglePressed = false;
            invalidate();
        }

        if(isMenuItemPressed) {
            if(mMenuItems.get(mPressedMenuItemID).getCallback() != null) {
                mMenuItems.get(mPressedMenuItemID).getCallback().onMenuItemPressed();
            }
            mMenuItems.get(mPressedMenuItemID)
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            isMenuItemPressed = false;
            invalidate();
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    //Determine the diameter and the radius based on device orientation
    if(w > h) {
        mDiameter = h;
        mRadius = mDiameter/2 - (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());
    } else {
        mDiameter = w;
        mRadius = mDiameter/2 - (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
    }
    //Init the draw arc Rect object
    mMenuRect = getRadialMenuRect(false);
    mMenuCenterButtonRect = getRadialMenuRect(true);
}
/**
 * Draw the toggle menu button text.
 * @param canvas
 * @param paint
 */
private void drawCenterText(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    paint.setColor(mToggleMenuTextColor);
    switch(mOrientation) {
    case VERTICAL_RIGHT:
        canvas.drawText(centerMenuText, getWidth() - paint.measureText(centerMenuText), getHeight()/2, paint);
        break;
    case VERTICAL_LEFT:
        canvas.drawText(centerMenuText, 2, getHeight()/2, paint);
        break;
    case HORIZONTAL_TOP:
        canvas.drawText(centerMenuText, (getWidth()/2) - (paint.measureText(centerMenuText)/2), textSize, paint);
        break;
    case HORIZONTAL_BOTTOM:
        canvas.drawText(centerMenuText, (getWidth()/2) - (paint.measureText(centerMenuText)/2), getHeight()/2 - (textSize), paint);
        break;
    }
}

/* Get the arc drawing rects
 * @param isCenterButton
 * @return*/
private RectF getRadialMenuRect(boolean isCenterButton) {
    int left, right, top, bottom;
    left = right = top = bottom= 0;
    switch(mOrientation) {
    case VERTICAL_RIGHT:
        if(isCenterButton) {
            left = getWidth() - (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            right = getWidth() + (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            top = (getHeight()/2) - (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            bottom = (getHeight()/2) + (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);              
        } else {
            left = getWidth() - (int) mRadius;
            right = getWidth() + (int) mRadius;
            top = (getHeight()/2) - (int) mRadius;
            bottom = (getHeight()/2) + (int) mRadius;
        }
        mStartAngle = 90;
        mViewAnchorPoints = new Point(getWidth(), getHeight()/2);
        break;
    case VERTICAL_LEFT:
        if(isCenterButton) {
            left = -(int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            right = (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            top = (getHeight()/2) - (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            bottom = (getHeight()/2) + (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
        } else {
            left = -(int) mRadius;
            right = (int) mRadius;
            top = (getHeight()/2) - (int) mRadius;
            bottom = (getHeight()/2) + (int) mRadius;
        }
        mStartAngle = 270;
        mViewAnchorPoints = new Point(0, getHeight()/2);
        break;
    case HORIZONTAL_TOP:
        if(isCenterButton) {
            left = (getWidth()/2) - (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            right = (getWidth()/2) + (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            top = -(int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            bottom = (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
        } else {
            left = (getWidth()/2) - (int) mRadius;
            right = (getWidth()/2) + (int) mRadius;
            top = -(int) mRadius;
            bottom = (int) mRadius;
        }
        mStartAngle = 0;
        mViewAnchorPoints = new Point(getWidth()/2, 0);
        break;
    case HORIZONTAL_BOTTOM:
        if(isCenterButton) {
            left = (getWidth()/2) - (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            right = (getWidth()/2) + (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            top = getHeight() - (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
            bottom = getHeight() + (int) (mRadius/mOpenButtonScaleFactor);
        } else {
            left = (getWidth()/2) - (int) mRadius;
            right = (getWidth()/2) + (int) mRadius;
            top = getHeight() - (int) mRadius;
            bottom = getHeight() + (int) mRadius;
        }
        mStartAngle = 180;
        mViewAnchorPoints = new Point(getWidth()/2, getHeight());
        break;
    }
    Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    Log.i(VIEW_LOG_TAG, " Top " + top + " Bottom " + bottom + " Left " + left + "  Right " + right);
    return new RectF(rect); 
}

/* Getter and setter methods*/

/**
 * Set the orientation the semi-circular radial menu.
 * There are four possible orientations only
 * VERTICAL_RIGHT , VERTICAL_LEFT , HORIZONTAL_TOP, 
 * HORIZONTAL_BOTTOM
 * @param orientation
 */
public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    mOrientation = orientation;
    mMenuRect = getRadialMenuRect(false);
    mMenuCenterButtonRect = getRadialMenuRect(true);
    invalidate();
}
public void addMenuItem(String idTag, SemiCircularRadialMenuItem mMenuItem) {
    mMenuItems.put(idTag, mMenuItem);
    invalidate();
}
public void removeMenuItemById(String idTag) {
    mMenuItems.remove(idTag);
    invalidate();
}
public void removeAllMenuItems() {
    mMenuItems.clear();
    invalidate();
}
public void dismissMenu() {
    isMenuVisible = false;
    centerMenuText = openMenuText;
    invalidate();
}
public float getShadowRadius() {
    return mShadowRadius;
}
public void setShadowRadius(int mShadowRadius) {
    this.mShadowRadius = mShadowRadius * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    invalidate();
}
public boolean isShowMenuText() {
    return isShowMenuText;
}
public void setShowMenuText(boolean isShowMenuText) {
    this.isShowMenuText = isShowMenuText;
    invalidate();
}
public int getOrientation() {
    return mOrientation;
}
public int getCenterRadialColor() {
    return centerRadialColor;
}
public void setCenterRadialColor(int centerRadialColor) {
    this.centerRadialColor = centerRadialColor;
    invalidate();
}
public int getShadowColor() {
    return mShadowColor;
}
public void setShadowColor(int mShadowColor) {
    this.mShadowColor = mShadowColor;
    invalidate();
}
public String getOpenMenuText() {
    return openMenuText;
}
public void setOpenMenuText(String openMenuText) {
    this.openMenuText = openMenuText;
    if(!isMenuTogglePressed)
        centerMenuText = openMenuText;
    invalidate();
}
public String getCloseMenuText() {
    return closeMenuText;
}
public void setCloseMenuText(String closeMenuText) {
    this.closeMenuText = closeMenuText;
    if(isMenuTogglePressed)
        centerMenuText = closeMenuText;
    invalidate();
}
public int getToggleMenuTextColor() {
    return mToggleMenuTextColor;
}
public void setToggleMenuTextColor(int mToggleMenuTextColor) {
    this.mToggleMenuTextColor = mToggleMenuTextColor;
    invalidate();
}
public float getTextSize() {
    return textSize;
}
public void setTextSize(int textSize) {
    this.textSize = textSize  * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mRadialMenuPaint.setTextSize(this.textSize);
    invalidate();
}
public int getOpenButtonScaleFactor() {
    return mOpenButtonScaleFactor;
}
public void setOpenButtonScaleFactor(int mOpenButtonScaleFactor) {
    this.mOpenButtonScaleFactor = mOpenButtonScaleFactor;
    invalidate();
}
```

}

```
This class is for the radial items:
SemiCircularMenuItem.java

public class SemiCircularRadialMenuItem {

    private String mMenuID;
    private Drawable mIcon;
    private String mText;
    private int mBackgroundColor;
    private int mMenuNormalColor;
    private int mMenuSelectedColor;
    private int mTextColor;
    private Path mPath;
    private RectF mBounds;
    private OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed mCallback;
    private int mIconDimen;

    public interface OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed {
        public void onMenuItemPressed();
    }
    public SemiCircularRadialMenuItem(String id, Drawable mIcon, String mText) {
        super();
        this.mMenuID = id;
        this.mIcon = mIcon;
        this.mText = mText;
        this.mMenuNormalColor = Color.WHITE;
        this.mMenuSelectedColor = Color.LTGRAY;
        this.mBackgroundColor = mMenuNormalColor;
        this.mTextColor = Color.BLACK;
        this.mIconDimen = 64;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBounds = new RectF();
    }
    public int getTextColor() {
        return mTextColor;
    }
    public void setTextColor(int mTextColor) {
        this.mTextColor = mTextColor;
    }
    public String getMenuID() {
        return mMenuID;
    }
    public int getIconDimen() {
        return mIconDimen;
    }
    public void setIconDimen(int mIconDimen) {
        this.mIconDimen = mIconDimen;
    }
    public Path getMenuPath() {
        return mPath;
    }
    public RectF getBounds() {
        return mBounds;
    }
    public void setMenuPath(RectF menuButtonRect, RectF menuRect, float StartArc, float ArcWidth, float radius, Point anchorPoint) {
        int left, right, top, bottom;
        left = right = top = bottom= 0;
        //Draw the widget path
        mPath.arcTo(menuRect, StartArc, ArcWidth);
        mPath.arcTo(menuButtonRect, StartArc + ArcWidth, -ArcWidth);
        mPath.close();
        mPath.computeBounds(mBounds, true);
        //Get the drawable bounds
        Point drawableCenter = pointOnCircle((radius - (radius/5)),StartArc + (ArcWidth/2),anchorPoint);
        left = (int) drawableCenter.x - (mIconDimen/2);
        top = (int) drawableCenter.y - (mIconDimen/2);
        right = left + (mIconDimen);
        bottom = top + (mIconDimen);
        mIcon.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    private Point pointOnCircle(float radius, float angleInDegrees, Point origin) {    
        int x = (int)(radius * Math.cos(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.x;
        int y = (int)(radius * Math.sin(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.y;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return mIcon;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }
    public void setOnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed(OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed mCallback) {
        this.mCallback = mCallback;
    }
    public OnSemiCircularRadialMenuPressed getCallback() {
        return mCallback;
    }
    public int getBackgroundColor() {
        return mBackgroundColor;
    }   
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        this.mBackgroundColor = color;
    }
    public int getMenuNormalColor() {
        return mMenuNormalColor;
    }
    public void setMenuNormalColor(int mMenuNormalColor) {
        this.mMenuNormalColor = mMenuNormalColor;
    }
    public int getMenuSelectedColor() {
        return mMenuSelectedColor;
    }
    public void setMenuSelectedColor(int mMenuSelectedColor) {
        this.mMenuSelectedColor = mMenuSelectedColor;
    }
}


Now the XML files:

activity_main.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>

This is the first fragment:
timeline_profile.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timelineTv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/timeline"
            android:background="#614d28"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
            android:padding="@dimen/tab_padding"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileTv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/profile"
            android:background="#8f7f61"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
            android:padding="@dimen/tab_padding"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_timeLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/paddingTopValue"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/paddingTopValue"/>
</LinearLayout>

This is another fragment:
add_fragment.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/linAdd">
    <com.bpd.utils.SemiCircularRadialMenu
        android:id="@+id/radial_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is this SemiCircularRadialMenu??Can you post screenShot

Comment: Hi @Anuj, can u plz tell me the process to post the screenshot?

Comment: Did you wrote the code to use that SemiCircularRadialMenu or used some library?

Comment: Its realy awesome,please can you teach me or give my some links from where you learned

Comment: i mean i copied it. @Anuj

Comment: search for android radial menu